# Trigger onClick handler, when it's overlapped with element that has onMouseMove, onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave handlers in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, onclick, onmousemove

So, I have an svg graph rendered in React. This SVG graph has a rect element that overlaps the whole svg (width 100% and height 100%). The code looks like this:

```html
<RectStyled
    ref={rectRef}
    width={dimensions.width}
    height={dimensions.height}
    onMouseOver={toggleHover}
    onMouseLeave={toggleHover}
    onMouseMove={handleMove}
/>
```

I need the `onMouseMove` handler, since I want to know the mouse (cursor) position at any time, so I can display tooltips and so on.

Now the problem is that I want to have a button at the bottom right corner of the svg, and I want to attach an `onClick` event handler to that button. The handler will, of course, have some logic of it's own.

The code for the button is as follows:

```html
<button
    onClick={e => {
            console.log('is it triggered');
            // other logic, not relevant for the issue
    }}
>
    Analyse
</button>
```

`onClick` is **not** being triggered, because event handlers of `RectStyled` are overlapping everything. In the actual DOM, the `rect` element is rendered last. The `button` element is a sibling (not a child) of `rect`.

I tried using other svg elements, like `text` or `path`, but got the same result — only `onMouseMove` is triggered.

What do I have to do to ensure `onClick` gets triggered?